# How to pop out the objects from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 and have a JQuery DataTable in which the first column holds checkboxes. I'm keeping the selected rows objects in an array like the following for future manipulation. But my problem is how can I get access to each object from the last to the first one, something like I want to pop them out one by one and use them.

````js
var OTable = $("#myDummyTable").dataTable();

$("input[type=checkbox]:checked", OTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {

    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    var newRow = oTable.row(row);

    keepSelectedRows.push(newRow);
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

If there are elements in your array, and these elements are objects, you can just do

```
myArr.pop()
```

I'm assuming that your array is an array of objects!

To access that element,

```
let el = myArr.pop();
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, How can I see the content of keepSelectedRows?

Comment: Try doing ```console.log(keepSelectedRows);```, this will log the content of this variable to console, which in your case seems to be an array..